# filter dataframe by numeric variable, lm(), and extract slope

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I want to apply different levels of a numeric filter (e.g. `seq(10,80, by=2)`) and then stitch back these into a single dataframe for comparison against another variable. I can currently do this, but I'm hoping there is a better way since I am just copying and pasting code and then joining everything back. The end result that I want is what I have, each filter step as its own column with the slope parameter from lm() extracted.

```
Source: local data frame [23 x 17]

                           File FruitNum      est10
                         <fctr>    <int>      <dbl>
1  IMG_7888.JPGcolcorrected.jpg        2 -4.0000000
2  IMG_7888.JPGcolcorrected.jpg        4 -2.0000000
3  IMG_7889.JPGcolcorrected.jpg        1 -0.8178571
4  IMG_7889.JPGcolcorrected.jpg        2 -2.1000000
5  IMG_7890.JPGcolcorrected.jpg        1 -2.8000000
6  IMG_7892.JPGcolcorrected.jpg        3 -2.3571429
7  IMG_7895.JPGcolcorrected.jpg        1 -0.4000000
8  IMG_7896.JPGcolcorrected.jpg        3 -6.5000000
9  IMG_7898.JPGcolcorrected.jpg        1 -3.0000000
10 IMG_7888.JPGcolcorrected.jpg        1         NA
..                          ...      ...        ...
Variables not shown: est15 <dbl>, est20 <dbl>, est25 <dbl>,
  est30 <dbl>, est35 <dbl>, est40 <dbl>, est45 <dbl>, est50
  <dbl>, est55 <dbl>, est60 <dbl>, est65 <dbl>, est70 <dbl>,
  est75 <dbl>, est80 <dbl>.
```

I'm currently using an NSE pipeline in the hadleyverse and would like to stay there, but am happy to see base, data.table or other implementations.  I've been looking at purrr, but I'm unsure how to map the filter to a variable inline.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)
library(broom)

cukeDataDL <- read.delim("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/bhive01/e7508f552db0415fec1749d0a390c8e5/raw/a12386d43c936c2f73d550dfdaecb8e453d19cfe/widthtest.tsv") 

cukeDatatest <-
    cukeDataDL %>%
    mutate(ObjectWidth = strsplit(as.character(cukeDatatest$ObjectWidth), ',')) %>%  # split ObjectWidth into a nested column containing a vector
    unnest() %>% # unnest nested column, melting data to long form
    mutate(ObjectWidth = as.integer(ObjectWidth)) %>%   # convert data to integer
    group_by(File, FruitNum) %>%
    mutate(rownum = row_number()) #location within File x fruit

estimate10 <- 
    cukeDatatest %>% 
    filter(ObjectWidth < 0.10 * max(ObjectWidth) & rownum > mean(rownum)) %>% # filtering for 10% of maxwidth and second half of fruit
    by_slice(~tidy( lm(ObjectWidth ~ rownum, data = .))) %>% #broom to clean up models and get coef()s
    unnest() %>% #pull out nested information
    filter(term == "rownum") %>% #only interested in slope value
    select(File, FruitNum, est10 = estimate) #get rid of uninteresting columns and rename estimate for join

estimate15 <- 
    cukeDatatest %>% 
    filter(ObjectWidth < 0.15 * max(ObjectWidth) & rownum > mean(rownum)) %>%
    by_slice(~tidy( lm(ObjectWidth ~ rownum, data = .))) %>%
    unnest() %>%
    filter(term == "rownum") %>%
    select(File, FruitNum, est15 = estimate)

estimate20 <- 
    cukeDatatest %>% 
    filter(ObjectWidth < 0.20 * max(ObjectWidth) & rownum > mean(rownum)) %>%
    by_slice(~tidy( lm(ObjectWidth ~ rownum, data = .))) %>%
    unnest() %>%
    filter(term == "rownum") %>%
    select(File, FruitNum, est20 = estimate) 

estimate25 <- 
    cukeDatatest %>% 
    filter(ObjectWidth < 0.25 * max(ObjectWidth) & rownum > mean(rownum)) %>%
    by_slice(~tidy( lm(ObjectWidth ~ rownum, data = .))) %>%
    unnest() %>%
    filter(term == "rownum") %>%
    select(File, FruitNum, est25 = estimate) 

estimate30 <- 
    cukeDatatest %>% 
    filter(ObjectWidth < 0.30 * max(ObjectWidth) & rownum > mean(rownum)) %>%
    by_slice(~tidy( lm(ObjectWidth ~ rownum, data = .))) %>%
    unnest() %>%
    filter(term == "rownum") %>%
    select(File, FruitNum, est30 = estimate)

estimate35 <- 
    cukeDatatest %>% 
    filter(ObjectWidth < 0.35 * max(ObjectWidth) & rownum > mean(rownum)) %>%
    by_slice(~tidy( lm(ObjectWidth ~ rownum, data = .))) %>%
    unnest() %>%
    filter(term == "rownum") %>%
    select(File, FruitNum, est35 = estimate)

estimate40 <- 
    cukeDatatest %>% 
    filter(ObjectWidth < 0.40 * max(ObjectWidth) & rownum > mean(rownum)) %>%
    by_slice(~tidy( lm(ObjectWidth ~ rownum, data = .))) %>%
    unnest() %>%
    filter(term == "rownum") %>%
    select(File, FruitNum, est40 = estimate) 

estimate45 <- 
    cukeDatatest %>% 
    filter(ObjectWidth < 0.45 * max(ObjectWidth) & rownum > mean(rownum)) %>%
    by_slice(~tidy( lm(ObjectWidth ~ rownum, data = .))) %>%
    unnest() %>%
    filter(term == "rownum") %>%
    select(File, FruitNum, est45 = estimate) 

estimate50 <- 
    cukeDatatest %>% 
    filter(ObjectWidth < 0.50 * max(ObjectWidth) & rownum > mean(rownum)) %>%
    by_slice(~tidy( lm(ObjectWidth ~ rownum, data = .))) %>%
    unnest() %>%
    filter(term == "rownum") %>%
    select(File, FruitNum, est50 = estimate) 

estimate55 <- 
    cukeDatatest %>% 
    filter(ObjectWidth < 0.55 * max(ObjectWidth) & rownum > mean(rownum)) %>%
    by_slice(~tidy( lm(ObjectWidth ~ rownum, data = .))) %>%
    unnest() %>%
    filter(term == "rownum") %>%
    select(File, FruitNum, est55 = estimate) 

estimate60 <- 
    cukeDatatest %>% 
    filter(ObjectWidth < 0.60 * max(ObjectWidth) & rownum > mean(rownum)) %>%
    by_slice(~tidy( lm(ObjectWidth ~ rownum, data = .))) %>%
    unnest() %>%
    filter(term == "rownum") %>%
    select(File, FruitNum, est60 = estimate) 

estimate65 <- 
    cukeDatatest %>% 
    filter(ObjectWidth < 0.65 * max(ObjectWidth) & rownum > mean(rownum)) %>%
    by_slice(~tidy( lm(ObjectWidth ~ rownum, data = .))) %>%
    unnest() %>%
    filter(term == "rownum") %>%
    select(File, FruitNum, est65 = estimate) 

estimate70 <- 
    cukeDatatest %>% 
    filter(ObjectWidth < 0.70 * max(ObjectWidth) & rownum > mean(rownum)) %>%
    by_slice(~tidy( lm(ObjectWidth ~ rownum, data = .))) %>%
    unnest() %>%
    filter(term == "rownum") %>%
    select(File, FruitNum, est70 = estimate) 

estimate75 <- 
    cukeDatatest %>% 
    filter(ObjectWidth < 0.75 * max(ObjectWidth) & rownum > mean(rownum)) %>%
    by_slice(~tidy( lm(ObjectWidth ~ rownum, data = .))) %>%
    unnest() %>%
    filter(term == "rownum") %>%
    select(File, FruitNum, est75 = estimate)
estimate80 <- 
    cukeDatatest %>% 
    filter(ObjectWidth < 0.80 * max(ObjectWidth) & rownum > mean(rownum)) %>%
    by_slice(~tidy( lm(ObjectWidth ~ rownum, data = .))) %>%
    unnest() %>%
    filter(term == "rownum") %>%
    select(File, FruitNum, est80 = estimate) 

  # put everything together  
allEstimates <- 
    full_join(estimate10, estimate15) %>%
    full_join(., estimate20) %>%
    full_join(., estimate25) %>%
    full_join(., estimate30) %>%
    full_join(., estimate35) %>%
    full_join(., estimate40) %>%
    full_join(., estimate45) %>%
    full_join(., estimate50) %>%
    full_join(., estimate55) %>%
    full_join(., estimate60) %>%
    full_join(., estimate65) %>%
    full_join(., estimate70) %>%
    full_join(., estimate75) %>%
    full_join(., estimate80) 
allEstimates #print it out
```

Comment: It would be better if you were more clear on what exactly you were trying to do rather than showing how you've done it. Give the desired output for the sample input.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @MrFlick. The output is the desired output. What I want help with is removing all the repetition from my code. I'm sure it can be done, I'm just not sure where to get started. I refactored the code to make it much shorter and edited the description for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Much shorter! Thanks @NoamRoss via twitter.

1. Using map, you supply the series you want to iterate over `seq(10,80, by=2)`
2. It creates a series of dataframes for each iteration
3. Create a namesafe column description to use for column names later
4. Use bind_rows() to bring everything together
5. Use spread() to make each level of PCTwidth a column
6. Profit???

``

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)
library(broom)

cukeDataDL <- read.delim("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/bhive01/e7508f552db0415fec1749d0a390c8e5/raw/a12386d43c936c2f73d550dfdaecb8e453d19cfe/widthtest.tsv")
cukeDatatest <- 
    cukeDataDL %>%
        select(File, FruitNum, ObjectWidth) %>%
        # split ObjectWidth into a nested column containing a vector
        mutate(ObjectWidth = strsplit(as.character(.$ObjectWidth), ',')) %>% 
        # unnest nested column, melting data to long form
        unnest() %>% 
        # convert data to integer
        mutate(ObjectWidth = as.integer(ObjectWidth)) %>%   # convert data to integer
        group_by(File, FruitNum) %>%
        mutate(rownum = row_number())
allEstimates <-
    map(seq(0.10,0.80, by=0.02), function(x) {
        cukeDatatest %>% 
            filter(ObjectWidth < x * max(ObjectWidth) & rownum > mean(rownum)) %>% 
            by_slice(~tidy( lm(ObjectWidth ~ rownum, data = .))) %>% 
            unnest() %>% 
            filter(term == "rownum") %>% 
            select(File, FruitNum, estimate) %>%
            mutate(PCTwidth = paste("est", round(x*100), sep=""))
        }
    ) %>% 
    bind_rows() %>%
    spread(., PCTwidth, estimate)

allEstimates #print everything out
```